# Dynamic conditions in IF function in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, dynamic-variables

I'm using Google Sheets and I have this issue:
is there any way to save the logical condition in the IF function into a cell?
For example, we have this function:

=IF(B1>0; "Positive"; "Negative")

Could I in some way save condition 'B1>0' into a cell A1 and use like so:

=IF(A1; "Positive"; "Negative")

Obviously I can't do it like that because A1 is not a bool value. Is there any way to convert it into bool or save that condition in any other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put in A1

```
=B1>0
```

A1 will display true or false according to the value in B1, and then you will be able to write

```
=IF(A1; "Positive"; "Negative")
```

If you want to store only the condition, put in A1

```
=">0"
```

then write

```
=evaluate(B1&A1)
```

with a custom function

```
function evaluate( formula ) {
  if (formula.charAt(0) === '=') formula = formula.substring(1);
  return eval(formula)
}
```

since evaluate() doesn't exist in google sheets